# Does the RoundhousE (database migration utility) support running SQL Server scripts in SQLCMD mode?

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, sqlcmd, database-versioning, roundhouse

It would be awesome if this super RoundhousE database migration tool supported SQL Server scripts in SQLCMD mode. The Visual Studio Data Tools generate scripts in SQLCMD mode. It would be nice to add these SQLCMD mode scripts to the RoundHouse migrations without any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

No, the RoundhousE database migration utility does not support SQL Server scripts in SQLCMD mode, but it can be done easily by downloading RoundhousE source code and extending the SqlServerDatabase class. See the proposed implementation at https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/issues/228